Выдает ошибку import'а при версии aiogram-3.13.0
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types 
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InputFile
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.fsm import State, StatesGroup
import requests
import logging


ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram.utils'


Пишу бота и при запуске кода выдает ошибку импорта. Однако установлена новейшая версия aiogram

Явно же видно, что у вас Python 3.9, зачем ставить метку 3.6?

С версией aiogram3.x executor был выведен из фреймоворка. Теперь запуск осуществляется обычным asyncio.run().

Современная версия Питон - 3.12.6. Чем быстрее избавитесь от привычки использовать from, тем быстрее закончатся Ваши подобные проблемы. Не исключаю также, что и нет никакого executor там. И вот результаты поиска: Проблема в том, что в версии 3 библиотеки aiogram модуль executor был полностью удален. Вместо этого вы можете использовать Dispatcher напрямую для запуска опроса API или обработки вебхуков.


Первые два предложения лишние. Советы, не имеющие отношения к вопросу. 2) Добавьте пример правильного кода. 3) Минус не я поставил.


А чем вам from не угодил?

Советы НЕ лишние. Лекции читаю, но тем, кто слушает. Ни одного слова, никогда и нигде я не говорю зря. У меня всё работает, потому что думаю головой и потому что у меня за плечами 30 лет программирования, без "папенек" с советами в мешке. Никому ничего не навязываю. Моё дело посоветовать. Будут ли слушать советы мне всё равно. Ответ на вопрос о from очевиден. Если неочевиден до сих пор, то и я не помогу. Не всё, что пишут в книжках, надо выполнять - для начала...

@FoxFox У меня больше 30 лет программирования, так что не надо тут )  К чему была фраза "Современная версия Питон - 3.12.6.", что она значит? Что нужно использовать только самый последний Питон? Я лично не понял ни сути ни смысла этого вашего совета. Далее. Чем же плох from? Если из пакета нужен один класс, с понятным, не смешивающимся с другими классами и пакетами названием, то чем же это плохо то? Например, я хочу использовать класс LinearRegression из модуля sklearn.linear_models, что вы предлагаете взамен from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression и чем это будет лучше?

Можно я не буду читать лекций о необходимости пользоваться современной версией? Питон  пишут программисты. Это тоже люди, а время не стоит на месте. Хочется проблем, связанных с найденными и исправленными багами? Хочется, чтоб новые функции и возможности не работали в приложениях? Хочется странных и непонятных глюков? Хочется чтоб возникали конфликты с модулями, которые ТОЖЕ развиваются? Да пожалуйста!  Но никто ждать не будет "личностного роста". Я разработчик. Первое, что я спрашиваю, когда мне говорят о проблеме: у Вас последняя версия приложения? C этого начинается предметный разговор.

@FoxFox Вы когда-нибудь писали крупные проекты для крупных компаний? Вы понимаете, что переделка крупного проекта под каждую очередную версию языка и библиотек - это время и деньги? Что такая переработка проекта требует полного тестирования каждый раз, а это тоже время и деньги? Это какая-то сферическая разработка в вакууме, когда у вас есть возможность переходить на новую версию языка и библиотек прямо сразу когда они выходят. Не говоря уже о том, что переход одной библиотеки на новую версию может ломать работу других библиотек, которые под неё ещё не успели переписать.

О чём это и зачем? Это о from? Я не разве не всё уже сказал? Немного повторю. Я думаю головой и когда читаю книгу, не вижу в ней фигу. Питон 3.12.6 появился вчера. Я перекомпилировал все приложения прямо вчера, НИ СЕКУНДЫ не сомневаясь, что у меня будет всё работать. До того я программировал базы данных в Visual FoxPro? До сих пор работают. Потом был Powershell в комбинации с C#. Меня даже приблизительно никогда не интересовал вопрос, будет ли после очередного обновления мой проект работать. Да, глюки есть у всех. Но у меня они бывают не по вине обновлений.

Обратите внимание, я и сюда сбрасываю преимущественно полностью готовые утилиты. Они работают. Потому что я думаю головой.

@FoxFox Никогда не задумывался, что когда ты обновляешь какую-то библиотеку, новая версия может содержать в себе уязвимости. Например xz-utils и CVE-2024-3094. Если ты так любишь читать, то мог бы прочесть в интернете к чему приводит безрассудное обновление всего и вся

Не обновляйте, чтение само по себе полезно.
